# Compare localized decimal in Angular

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm using `i18n` for my application. Currently, I have a column with a decimal value.

For `en`, it will be 0.10.
For `fr`, it will be 0,10.

My problem is I am comparing this column to a whole number.

```
return myDecimalValue < 5;
```

Now this works fine for `en`, but fails on `fr`. Is there a way I can format my decimal value in a way I can compare it properly to a whole number?

Comment: Do you use the [decimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) ?

Comment: No, I'm not using it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Wih the previous version (2.x), I used a custom pipe whick uses `.toLocaleString()`.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'format' })
export class NumberFormatter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(_number: any, lang: string) {
        if (_number) {
            let floatNumber = parseFloat(_number);
            let lang = "fr-FR";
            if (!lang || lang == "fr") {
                lang = "fr-FR";
            } else if (lang == "en") {
                lang = "en-US";
            }
            return floatNumber.toLocaleString(lang);
        }
    }
}
```

And into view the template:

```
<p>{{ decimal | format:'en' }}</p>
```